# Tikz animation never stop compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

Why this MWE does never stop compiling generating tons of pdf pages ?

```
\documentclass[french,xcolor=dvipsnames,9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=.4cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=.4cm}

\newcommand{\Rect}[2][blue]{%
    \begin{scope}[#2]
        \draw[draw=#1,fill=#1!25,join=round]
            (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle ;
        \filldraw[#1] (0,0) rectangle (.2,.2) ; 
    \end{scope}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\only<1->{\Rect{}}

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using \i+2] in {1,...,2} {%
    \only<\j>{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3*\i/20,0)}]
        \Rect{}
    \end{scope}
    }
    }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm guessing but try with `int(\i+2)` in the evaluate of foreach. I don't think `\only` is that smart.

Comment: Bingo ! fill free to write an answer. If not `\only`, what else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't check it but it might happen that the argument of `\only` macro is compared to the framecounter value and since TikZ arithmetic `\i+2` returns a decimal point such as `3.0` this comparison never gets satisfied. Hence you need to convert the result to integer to make it `3`. So

```
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+2)] in {1,...,2} {%
```

does it.